# Gradle IntelliJ project: Using self-signed certificate MAC - Password Error

Tags: java, gradle, keystore, keytool

I have added my self-certificate *.pem to the cacerts in my security folder.
This has been confirmed with keytool.
I can open the cacerts using the standard password "changeit"
I added the following code to my gradle.properties file:

```
org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx4g -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/zulu-17.jdk/Contents/Home/lib/security/cacerts -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword=changeit
```

however, when I go to build my gradle project both in terminal and in intelliJ, I get the error:

```
org.apache.http.ssl.SSLInitializationException: Keystore was tampered with, or password was incorrect
```

The password works in terminal when using keytool so confused as to why I am getting this error. Any help is appreciated.

Background: reason for doing all this is I am building a project behind my firms security.